Backlighting a button on a website in mobile emulation
When you click on a button in the mobile browser emulation, the button remains highlighted.
When you click on a button On the desktop version of the browser, everything works correctly.
How to fix this?


.button-coontainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 90vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn-link:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

.btn-link:active {
    background-color: #004080;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
<div class="button-coontainer">
    <a class="btn-link" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;">
        My button
    </a>
</div>




can you give me more details?

This is used for giving the website visitor a visual feedback, in mobile devices it is a useful thing to not remove.
Basically, it is a feature to show the user that the button is clicked, which removing wouldn't be good.
But if you're willing to remove it still, you can use this CSS code:
.btn-link {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}

This will help with removing the highlight issue you're having.

On mobile, it works similarly to hover when the touch starts.
There is a way to adjust it to the viewport size, but It is desirable to show the behavior to the user.

The code below changes hover color as intended in PC width
When clicked on mobile, it is not fixed with hover color and maintains the existing button color.



.button-coontainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 90vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn-link:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

.btn-link:active {
    background-color: #004080;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-link:hover {
    background-color: #007bff;
  }
}
<div class="button-coontainer">
    <a class="btn-link" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;">
        My button
    </a>
</div>




I assume you want the :hover state to not apply on mobile devices. So you can apply @media (hover: hover). Something like this:


.button-coontainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn-link:hover {
  @media (hover: hover) {
    background-color: #0056b3;
  }
}

.btn-link:active {
  background-color: #004080;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
<div class="button-coontainer">
  <a class="btn-link" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;">
    My button
  </a>
</div>



